# How to get prediction beyond linear regression result using python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to display the number of days (prediction) beyond linear regression result. I have managed to display the data using `matplotlib` and created a `predict()` function to display the values based in the number of days but the data is outputting wrong, higher than the initial output. Since the straight line is aiming down and the higher value is `85.15`.

```
import area as area
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
from sklearn import linear_model

# date = x, cases = y
# 1- Retrieve the data
df = pd.read_csv("cases-challenge.csv")
x = df.days

y = df.cases
# 2- Iterate the data

# get the mean of x and y
xmean = x.mean()
ymean = y.mean()

df['diffx'] = xmean - x
df['diffx_squared'] = df.diffx ** 2
SSxx = df.diffx_squared.sum()

df['diffy'] = ymean - y
SSxy = (df.diffx * df.diffy).sum()

m = SSxx / SSxy
b = ymean - m * xmean


def predict(value):
    # value = x
    for i in range(value):
        # straight line = m*x+y
       print(i, ':', m * i + b)


predict(6)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, m*x+b, 'r')
plt.show()
```

The input `cases-challenge.csv`:

```
days, cases
18,   85.15
19,   83.5
20,   82.5
21,   80.73
22,   78.77
23,   77.86
24,   75.96
25,   75.85
26,   74.79
27,   72.79
```

output in terminal using `6` as value in the `predict()`:

```
0 : 95.61300163132137
1 : 94.86531266992931
2 : 94.11762370853725
3 : 93.36993474714518
4 : 92.62224578575312
5 : 91.87455682436106
```

Matplotlib output:

[image]

Comment: I added the `- xmean` in the `print(i, '->', int(m * i + b - xmean))`. So I got a aprox value of the trend line.